# CMD runs command, but in .bat it is not working

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I have this command.

```
for /r "C:\folder" %a in (*.jpg) do magick mogrify -resize 580x320 "%~a"
```

And it's working in command line, but when I create a `.bat` file from it then it's not working.

Comment: Did you remember to double up `%`? `%` in the command line needs to be `%%` in a batch file.

Comment: No I used this command as I posted. I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: In command line, enter `help for`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the right interpretation.

```
for /r "C:\folder" %%a in (*.jpg) do magick mogrify -resize 580x320 "%%~a"
```

I forgot double `%%`.

Now it's working when I create and use `.bat` file.

Comment: I believe you already know to accept your own answer **after the limit**...